# PHP class declaration

Tags: php

Is there any way to set explicit type to object field in php? Something like this

```
class House{
       private Roof $roof
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, there isn't. PHP variables can always be of any type. But you can enforce a type in the setter:

```
public function setRoof(Roof $roof) {
  $this->roof = $roof;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can only enforce objects or arrays, but not "primitive" types like float or string.

Comment: Had you a setter that expected a primitive type, `bool` for example, you could always `assert('is_bool($value)');`.

Comment: @svens: FWIW, PHP development added scalar type hinting on 5/20/2010.  I'm not sure when that will make it into an official release, though.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use PHP code to declare the type of an object field.

But you can put type *hints* in [docblock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) comments:

```
class House{
       /**
        * @var Roof
        */
       private $roof
}
```

This still doesn't make the code enforce types, but some IDE tools understand the docblocks and may warn you if you use this variable without conforming to the type hint.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for PHP's Type Hinting. It works great on function/method calls. Here's the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not just assign $roof to a new Roof()?

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the following before using the member

```
if (!$this->roof instanceof Roof) {

    throw new Exception('$this->roof is not an instance of Roof');
}
```